# ASP MVC Postal RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine, postal

I'm trying to use ASP MVC Postal in a background job to send emails as follows:

```
    public void CommentCreated(Comment comment, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));
        var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
        engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));

        var emailService = new Postal.EmailService(engines);

        var email = new CommentCreatedEmail
        {
            To = user.Email,
            From = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpEMailFrom"],
            Subject = "Comment Created"
            Comment = comment,
            User = user

        };

        emailService.Send(email);

    }
```

My view CommentCreated.cshtml is as follows:

```
@model MyApp.Models.CommentCreatedEmail
To: @Model.To
From: @Model.From
Subject: @Model.Subject

<p>
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Comment", new { id = @Model.Comment.Id }, "http")">@Url.Action("Details", "Comment", new { id = @Model.Comment.Id }, "http")</a>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException' in RazorEngine.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpCompileException' in System.Web.dll
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Put exception handling in to catch and identify where the error is occuring

```
public void CommentCreated(Comment comment, ApplicationUser user)
{
    try{
        var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));
        var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
        engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));

        var emailService = new Postal.EmailService(engines);

        var email = new CommentCreatedEmail
        {
            To = user.Email,
            From = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpEMailFrom"],
            Subject = "Comment Created"
            Comment = comment,
            User = user

        };

        emailService.Send(email);
    }
    catch(TemplateCompilationException ex)
    {
        foreach (var compilerError in ex.CompilerErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1} - Line {2} Column {3} in {4}", compilerError.ErrorNumber, compilerError.ErrorText, compilerError.Line, compilerError.Column, compilerError.FileName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is the following line ` <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Comment", new { id = @Model.Comment.Id }, "http")">@Url.Action("Details", "Comment", new { id = @Model.Comment.Id }, "http")</a>` When I remove this line it work. So the razor engine doesn't seem to be fully functional when used outside asp.net.

Comment: I haven't used Postal before but given that RazorEngine is performing the transformation, then the issue is more then likely due to the fact that RazorEngine doesn't support @Html or @Url functionality. So you will need to rewrite the link as `<a href="/comment/details/@Model.Comment.Id">link</a>` instead

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line :

```
Subject = "Comment Created"
```

is missing a comma (,) after it, shouldn't it be

```
Subject = "Comment Created",
```

Answer (score 0):

Razor Engine have some limitations outside the MVC world, so, a lot of things related to it won't work at all.

I've run into this problem recently and my "solution" was to set the redirect base URL inside app config and combine it at run time, something like this:

```
var email = new CommentCreatedEmail
    {
        To = user.Email,
        From = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpEMailFrom"],
        Subject = "Comment Created"
        Comment = comment,
        User = user
       CommentLink = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"] + "Comment/Details/"+comment.Id
    };
```

And in you .cshtml file:

```
@model MyApp.Models.CommentCreatedEmail
To: @Model.To
From: @Model.From
Subject: @Model.Subject

<p>
<a href="@Model.CommentLink">Comment</a>
```

Hope it helps!